# Give example of an event that satisfy given condition (probability).

Tags: probability

(a) Let $Ω = \{1, 2,.... 20\}$ and let $A$ be the set of even integers in $Ω$.

Assuming that all elements of $Ω$ are equally likely, give an example
with justification of events B and C such that
(i) A and B are independent.
(ii) A and C are not independent.

(b) Let $Ω = \{1, 2, 3 \}$ Give an example with justification of a probability P for which the events $\{1,2\}$ and $\{2,3\}$ are independent.

I can answer part (ii) of (a) where by selecting $C$ to be the set of primes in 
$Ω$, this will be enough to show $A$ and $C$ are not independent. But I am really struggling with coming up an event B which is **non-trivial**. as for Part (b) no idea at all.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For part (a), consider $B = \{1,2,3,4\}$.  Then $P(A \cap B) = P(\{2,4\})  = 1/10$, and $P(A)\cdot P(B) = 1/2 \cdot 1/5 = 1/10.$

For part (b),  You need a probability $P$ so that $P(\{1,2\}) \cdot P(\{2,3\}) = P(\{2\})$. What happens if you assign $P(\{3\}) = P(\{1\}) = 0$?

Comment: thank you i understand part (a). but for part (b) can you elaborate please i dont see from that how can define probability.

Comment: @MRK, the question is asking you for an example of a probability so that $\{1,2\}$ and $\{2,3\}$ are independent.  This means you have to assign probabilities to the three elements in $\Omega$.

Comment: wow i got you. Thanks very much appreciated.